# Como fazer um dropDown Menu sobrepor conteúdo da div

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando fazer um dropdown Menu, o problema é que eu gostaria que este menu sobreposse o conteúdo da div. Já tentei usar o `position: absolute`, funciona, entretando a div do dropdown Menu explode para fora da div a qual ele está contido.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".select").forEach((el)=> {
   el.addEventListener("click", function (e){
       this.classList.toggle("collapsed");
   });
});
```

```css
#submenuUser{
height: calc(100% - 210px);
width: 200px;
float: left;
margin-right: 5px;
border: solid 1px green;
background-color: #515151;
}
#listStyle{
list-style: none;
border-top: solid 1px grey;
padding-left: 0;
margin: 0;
}
#listStyle2{
list-style: none;
padding-left: 0;
margin-top: 5px;
}
#listStyle li{
border-bottom: solid 1px gray;
}
#listStyle li:hover{
background: #555;
}
#listStyle li a{
color: white;
height: 50px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}
.select{
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0;
color: #ffffff;
position: relative;
height: auto;
max-height: calc(50px * 8); /* max 8 element in list */
transition: 0.2s;
}
.select:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
background-color: #ffffff;
cursor: pointer;
width: 14px;
height: 14px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
top: 15px;
right: 15px;
}
.select:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
background-color: #4682B4;
cursor: pointer;
width: 14px;
height: 14px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
top: 20px;
right: 15px;
}
.collapsed {
max-height: 50px;
transition: 0.2s;
}
.collapsed:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
background-color: #ffffff;
cursor: pointer;
width: 14px;
height: 14px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
top: 10px;
right: 15px;
}
.collapsed:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
background-color: #4682B4;
cursor: pointer;
width: 14px;
height: 14px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
top: 5px;
right: 15px;
}
.option, .shown {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #515151;
}
.shown {
background-color: #4682B4;
font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div id="submenuUser">
<div class="select collapsed">
    <li class="shown">Sub Menu</li>
 <li class="option">Teste1</li>
 <li class="option">Teste2</li>
 <li class="option">Teste3</li>
 <li class="option">Teste4</li>
</div>
<ul id="listStyle">
    <li><a href="#">Teste1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Teste2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Teste3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Teste4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Como eu poderia resolver este problema ?

Comment: Cara como assim, não de para entender o que vc pretende... Qual quer era o comportamento que vc esperava? Parece funcionar normal... Vc tem uma imagem do layout, ou tem como explicar melhor ou editar o código com o problema que vc tem ai?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa colocar `position: relative` na div principal para que o elemento filho que tem `position: absolute` fique posicionado dentro relativo ao elemento pai, caso contrário ele ficará posicionado relativo ao body.

Como o elemento com absolute não ocupa espaço na div, será preciso usar um `padding-top` na segunda div para compensar e afasta-la do topo da div pai, para não ficar por baixo do submenu.

Veja abaixo as linhas no CSS com os comentários `/* AQUI */`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".select").forEach((el)=> {
   el.addEventListener("click", function (e){
       this.classList.toggle("collapsed");
   });
});
```

```css
#submenuUser{
height: calc(100% - 210px);
width: 200px;
float: left;
margin-right: 5px;
border: solid 1px green;
background-color: #515151;
position: relative; /* AQUI */
}
#listStyle{
list-style: none;
border-top: solid 1px grey;
padding-left: 0;
margin: 0;
padding-top: 50px; /* AQUI */

}
#listStyle2{
list-style: none;
padding-left: 0;
margin-top: 5px;
}
#listStyle li{
border-bottom: solid 1px gray;
}
#listStyle li:hover{
background: #555;
}
#listStyle li a{
color: white;
height: 50px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}
.select{
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0;
color: #ffffff;
position: absolute;
height: auto;
max-height: calc(50px * 8); /* max 8 element in list */
transition: 0.2s;
}
.select:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
background-color: #ffffff;
cursor: pointer;
width: 14px;
height: 14px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
top: 15px;
right: 15px;
}
.select:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
background-color: #4682B4;
cursor: pointer;
width: 14px;
height: 14px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
top: 20px;
right: 15px;
}
.collapsed {
max-height: 50px;
transition: 0.2s;
}
.collapsed:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
background-color: #ffffff;
cursor: pointer;
width: 14px;
height: 14px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
top: 10px;
right: 15px;
}
.collapsed:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
background-color: #4682B4;
cursor: pointer;
width: 14px;
height: 14px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
top: 5px;
right: 15px;
}
.option, .shown {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #515151;
}
.shown {
background-color: #4682B4;
font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div id="submenuUser">
<div class="select collapsed">
    <li class="shown">Sub Menu</li>
 <li class="option">Teste1</li>
 <li class="option">Teste2</li>
 <li class="option">Teste3</li>
 <li class="option">Teste4</li>
</div>
<ul id="listStyle">
    <li><a href="#">Teste1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Teste2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Teste3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Teste4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```